# Result of Davisson Germer experiment if electrons only exhibited particle nature

Tags: electrons, wave-particle-duality

The occurrence of minima and maxima in Davisson-Germer experiment confirm the wave nature of electrons.

Let us assume that the electrons do not posses any wave nature, and they only possess particle nature. In such case, how would the result of the experiment be?

According to me, the scattering of electrons would be completely random without any maxima and minima. If it would be anything else please let me know. Also , if possible please point to a source where I can find the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the electron has classical  particle nature then  one would expect phenomena like

- Coulomb or Rutherford Scattering
- Bremsstrahlung

But to observe these the setup should be such that to reduce other possibilities. But you would expect any possibility that is allowed by the interaction of charge particles with other charge particles.

---

There aren't many things as you leave out many possibilities that are totally quantum mechanical in nature.

Comment: 1. The surface of edges in principle is made of electrons - the outer electrons of atoms and molecules. These electrons have an electric field around and a magentic field.
2. The spins, pointing in the same directions as the electrons magnetic dipoles are interacting by Paulis exclusion principle. In short, (surface) electrons interact.
3…

Comment: 3. …Quasiparticles and collective excitations (which are closely related) are emergent phenomena that occur when a microscopically complicated system such as a solid behaves as if it contained different weakly interacting particles in vacuum. For example, as an electron travels through a semiconductor, its motion is disturbed in a complex way by its interactions with other electrons and with atomic nuclei.